# Debug Bootstrap 3 template

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, debugging, firebug

I'm converting psd to html, so I'm using bootstrap3. After I finished with converting, I have notice that I can not make `container-fluid` full `width` because I have left out some closing `div` tags, so I have turn on `firebug` and start inspecting `div's` one by one to see where do I need to close them, off course I have done it in the end, but it took me some time and that is fine.

I'm trying to understand how can I do this properly, and quickly, how can I properly debug a template, is there some work flow that will help me overcome this mistakes, and how can `firebug` help me speed up thing when I'm converting `psd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these links to be helpful when designing the structure of a web page with bootstrap:

[Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint)

[debug.css](http://firchow.net/bootstrap3-grid-debug/)